# access hidden attribute in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, attributes

I am downloading some data from [NHANES](https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nhanes/). I am using the package nhanesA available on CRAN.

```
library(nhanesA)    
x<-nhanes("DEMO_G")
str(attributes(x))
```

str(attributes(x)) list the three attributes in the dataframe x. Upon further examination, there is clearly a label attribute in the dataframe that deatils what the columns details. I was able to find a way to get this label in R.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking. do you just want the names of the columns  (beginning  "SEQN"   "SDDSRVYR" "RIDSTATR" ) or do you mean something else?

Comment: Try `View(x)` you'll see that there are column "labels" under the column names

Comment: No I do not want just the names of the columns. For instance if you view the dataframe in R Studio there are labels listed under the column names. These labels are what I'm trying to get at. The attributes function in r is not able to get these labels.

Comment: , I would like to get the labels into a vector as well so I need a way of attracting them.

Comment: With `View`   I just see the column names.

Comment: You might be running an outdated version of R Studio. Try using the Str function on the dataframe X you will see labels

Comment: OK,   Now I see the labels.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is that the `labels` you are seeing when you use `str(x)` (or `View(x)`) are attributes of the individual column names, not the `data.frame`. To retrieve them, you can do:

```
lapply(x, function(x) attributes(x)$label)
```

For viewing purposes:

```
head(lapply(x, function(x) attributes(x)$label))
#    $SEQN
#[1] "Respondent sequence number"

#$SDDSRVYR
#[1] "Data release cycle"

#$RIDSTATR
#[1] "Interview/Examination status"

#$RIAGENDR
#[1] "Gender"

#$RIDAGEYR
#[1] "Age in years at screening"

#$RIDAGEMN
#[1] "Age in months at screening - 0 to 24 mos"
```

Comment: Great! This is what I needed. I would have never thought that the column names could have attributes. Thanks again.